# sed to search for tab

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a configuration file in the following format

```
#   ra  y   1000000 \x2e\x72\x61\xfd
#   ost y   500000000   \x21\x42\x44\x4e
#   java    y   1000000 \xca\xfe\xba\xbe
```

This is what I want to do:

1. Search for `ra`, `ost`, `java`
2. If there is a **tab** before and after `ra`, `ost`, `java`, remove the `#` at the beginning

I am focusing on **tab** because the configuration file contains other text as well which might have `ra`, `ost`, `java` mentioned but they all will be separated with space before or after them because they would be mentioned in a paragraph and I don't want to uncomment those lines. Hence, I need to look for **tab**

---

[steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) already has answered. The edit is to mention a part of the file I was working on, on request of [John Goofy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/223883/john-goofy).

The file is like

```
# Scalpel configuration file
...
# Scalpel can read Foremost 0.69 configuration files, but Scalpel
...
# Real Audio Files
#      ra  y       1000000 \x2e\x72\x61\xfd
# MISCELLANEOUS
#      java        y       1000000 \xca\xfe\xba\xbe
# Outlook files
#      ost y       500000000       \x21\x42\x44\x4e
```

Although this configuration file didn't mention the list of names of file formats it can work on but if it had mentioned the names like

> # Scalpel works on **ra** **ost** **java**

Then the answer steeldriver gave is perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/^#\t\(ra\|ost\|java\)\t/ s/^#//' file
```

or (if extended regular expressions are supported) you can avoid some of the escaping

```
sed -E '/^#\t(ra|ost|java)\t/ s/^#//' file
```

Comment: Love you @steeldriver <3. Thank you so much.

Comment: What is the **different between** the the **normal regular expressions** in first command and **extended regular expression** in second command?

Comment: @steeldriver For both commands on my machine the output is the same like the input.

Comment: @JohnGoofy did you replace any of the spaces in the OP's example by tabs? unfortunately the forum formatting doesn't preserve tabs in pasted input

Comment: @steeldriver I have copied the given input into a file and check the tabs with `vim` if they are there.

Comment: @JohnGoofy Mentioned a part of the file I was working on as you requested. Do notice though that there are **tabs** before and after **ra**, **java**, and **ost** which are mentioned after the lines 'Real Audio Files', 'MISCELLANEOUS', and 'Outlook files' respectively. It's just that the comment markup in stack exchange does not allow **tabs**. It replaces **tabs** with **spaces**. And just to clarify, the `...` in the comments markup in the question indicates other data in file.